Pinescript v5 My code is to find the explosive candle, followed by boring candle/candles and ending explosive green candle,
Pinescript v5,  My code is to find the explosive candle, followed by boring candle/candles and ending with explosive green candle, and code has to search for the candles available on the chart for this pattern, but present is written in a way that it checks only
first candle of the session.like this
1Explosive candle  = session.isfirstbar
2boring candle= ta.barssince(1Explosive candle) +1
3Explosive candle = session.islastbar

Can we these conditions to find my setup on entire chart for 1st explosive candle followed by 1 or more boring candles and finally ending with green explosive candle.
I have tried to replace session.isfirstbar with explosive candle by giving certain body percentage threshold, but i want check for it in a loop for all the previous candles avialable on the chart

It looks like spam
